# How to target IE10+ and a specific screen size?

Tags: css, media-queries

I need to add some IE10/11 specific styling, but I only want it to happen on screen sizes of 768px+

I tried the following:

```
@media all and (-ms-high-contrast: none), (-ms-high-contrast: active) {
    @media (min-width:768px) {
        /* STYLING HERE */
    }
}
```

But this doesn't seem to work. If I remove `@media (min-width:768px)` the IE specific styling works, but then it display at all screen widths. How can I combine these media queries so that the CSS is only applied on IE10/11 for devices with a minimum width of 768px?

Answer (score 1):

Combining the 2, as below, seems to work. Any issues with this?

```
@media all and (min-width:768px) and (-ms-high-contrast: none), (-ms-high-contrast: active) {
    /* STYLING HERE */
}
```